# How to differ between this two rows index

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

I have a problem when the user adds a new row, I validate it for the required filed, 
So I want to know how to differentiate between the filter row, and row to add a new one

[image]

I check it with row index -1, when he filter some data the row index is -1 also, and he is forced to enter valid data to exit filter.

```
private void gv_PricingList_RowValidating(object sender, RowValidatingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex == -1)
        {
          //I do my logic here
          // e.cancle = true; if invalid data
        }
    }
```

I expect to enter the if condition when the user fills the row to add new one,
but the output is when he filters, it enters the condition

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what framework you are using. Assuming its winform gridview, you can try below option. e.IsValid property returns true or false flag indicating whether its a valid row or not.

```
private void gv_PricingList_RowValidating(object sender, RowValidatingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.IsValid == true && e.RowIndex == -1)
        {
          //Write your logic here
        }
    }
```

Comment: I use telerik gradview, and it doesn't contain e.IsValid

Comment: Why can't you try RowCreated event which will not even fire when filter is used and may solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for various row types as follows:

```
private void gv_PricingList_RowValidating(object sender, RowValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row is GridViewNewRowInfo)
    {
        //...
    }
    else if (e.Row is GridViewDataRowInfo)
    {
        //...
    }
    else if (e.Row is GridViewFilteringRowInfo)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

HTH.